# PHP Syntax Error on get_posts

Tags: php, get-posts

I have the following coding:

```
<?php
        global $post;
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => 8);
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
        echo '<a href='.the_permalink().'>'.the_title().'</a><br />';
        endforeach;
?>
```

Dreamweaver is highlighting a potential syntax error on line 6 & 7. I'm sure it's something very very simple but can someone point me in the right direction to solve this error please?

Comment: Seems okey to me. Did you tried running it? Sometimes Dreamweaver shows error where isn't any. Happened to me couple of times.

Comment: +1 @Sisir - happens to me a lot; might be the quotes missing around the link url.

Comment: I just put this into Dreamweaver CS5.5 (directly copy-pasted) and I'm not getting an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it is causing Dreamweaver to flag an error (try running it?), but on the second from last line you want to be using [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title). This returns the posts' title, whereas `the_title()` will echo it.

```
echo '<a href='.the_permalink().'>'.get_the_title().'</a><br />';
```

Comment: same with: `the_permalink()` -> `get_permalink($post->ID)`

Comment: Yup, I missed that one.